# Informix throws error Informix connection exception ERROR System error occurred in network function

Tags: informix

Informix Version 11.7.

When we try execute the query getting following exception as:

```
Informix connection exception ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider]
[Informix]System error occurred in network function
```

Before execution we checked the connection status is shown as 'OPEN' but still we are are getting this issue on and off.

Is anyone facing the similar issue?

Comment: That sounds like if the communication pipe with the server has been broken. The provider doesn't have any mechanism to automatically check that the link with the server is still up, so if for some reason the connection is not alive, next time the provider tries to use it (like running a query) it will throw that exception. Without getting a network trace is hard to find out if that's the case. A trace (e.g. SQLIDEBUG) will not show much, just an abruptly end session. 
If there is a firewall in the middle that could be closing the sockets (e.g timeout)

Comment: You're presumably running the application from .NET on Windows; is the Informix server also on WIndows?  Is it on the same machine or on a different machine?  If it is on a different machine, are there any network issues that could be causing disconnections?  You say version '11.7'; can you be more precise — the version number in full is something like `11.70.FC4` (possibly with a pair of letters such as `DE` after the `4`).  When did you last upgrade?  Have you considered moving to Informix 12.10 (current version 12.10.FC10)?  Are you using the DRDA connectivity?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Informix version used : 11.70.FC8  , database server is different one from application server. we hosted our application in Windows IIS server .